# How do I access the data in a bucket using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cloud

C:\Users\goura\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gsutil cp -r gs://299792458bucket/X
CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.
getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a location to copy to probably?

Try:

`gsutil cp -r gs://299792458bucket/X .`

(be sure you're in a directory that doesn't have a lot of other files in it)